# How to import / export content type in drupal 8?

Tags: drupal-8

How to import / export content type with their related contents from one website to another website in drupal 8?

Answer (score 9):

You'll find the drupal/console command **config:export:content:type** will help here.

Create a module and then run this command and it will do all the hard work for you:

```
drupal config:export:content:type --module=new_module --remove-uuid --remove-config-hash content_type_to_export
```

This will put it in the config/install directory for the module.  When you enable the module on your new site, it will run this automatically.

One gotcha I had was that it adds a couple of files for config already included in core. I just deleted them and it was all fine.  Basically if a yml file doesn't reference your content type in its file name, then you might not need it.

For more information:

```
drupal help config:export:content:type
```

Comment: The drush command worked as expected for Drupal 8.

Answer (score 3):

In this answer, I'll assume you have [Drush](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/) installed. (If you don't, you can manage your config files here /admin/config/development/configuration).

Ok so, for your SiteA, open your terminal and goto the SiteA folder.
Let's say you want your configs to be written in /sites/default/dev folder. So write the following command :

```
drush cex dev
```

It will export all of your website configurations. If you created new content types, they will be exported in the dev folder.

Now go to the dev folder of SiteA and copy every yml files related to your content type.

After, just paste them in the same folder but this time, in SiteB. 
Finally, in your terminal, goto SiteB folder and write the following command :

```
drush cim dev
```

**Edit**:

If you want to use dev folder, you'll need this config in your settings.php

```
$config_directories['dev'] = 'sites/default/dev';
```

Also, my answer only export content type configuration. Not it's content.

Comment: Exception: The configuration directory type 'dev' does not exist in                          /web/core/includes/bootstrap.inc:17

Comment: Well, you need to create it in order to save in it. (/sites/default/dev)

Comment: No, the folder exists.

Comment: that is for configuration, no content.

Comment: Indeed. Only for content type, not it's content. It's not possible to export content this way.

Answer (score 3):

You can export/Import the content type and its field type & field storage via Synchronize feature provide by Drupal 8.
Here this URL : admin/config/development/configuration

Comment: Unless I am missing something, this does NOT export actual content. Only the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If the source and destination websites are the same and you can import/export configuration, using configuration export/import is the best solution, if not, using [features module](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) should be good solution for you .

> The features module enables the capture and management of features in
>   Drupal. A feature is a collection of Drupal entities which taken
>   together satisfy a certain use-case.
>
> Features provides a UI and API for taking different site building
>   components from modules with exportables and bundling them together in
>   a single feature module. A feature module is like any other Drupal
>   module except that it contains additional information in its info file
>   so that configuration can be checked, updated, or reverted
>   programmatically.

Comment: Important comment here is that if you want to migrate data between 6 and 7 versions, and create feature in D6, you won't be able to enable it as module in D7. Nevertheless if you go to /admin/build/features you still will be able to enable yur feature from there!

Answer (score 0):

Try the Content synchronization feature from the Mix module, which allows you to export/import and recreate block contents, menu item links and taxonomy terms between environments (sites)

You can easily choose which items to sync via UI like below: [image]enter image description here